# Create a default constructor when using const strings

Tags: c++, default-constructor

I have a class that looks like this:

```
Person(int pID,
    int zipCode,
    float ySalary,
    const string& fName,
    const string& mName,
    const string& lName)
```

When I try to create a default constructor as shown below:

```
Person::Person(void){
    zipCode = NULL;
    pID = NULL;
    ySalary = NULL;
    fName = "";
    mName = "";
    lName = "";
}
```

I get an error saying there is no operator "=" that matches const std::string = const char[1];

Comment: I assume you want to be able to modify the names later? You shouldn't be using const references, just normal variables.

Comment: @MorphingDragon They said nothing about the member variables being `const`, they are just passing the strings by `const` reference to the constructor, which is probably a good idea anyway.

Comment: "I have a class that looks like this" and the error message is saying the left operand is const.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the member initializer list to initialize `const` reference member variables:

```
Person::Person(void) :
    zipCode(NULL) ,
    pID(NULL) ,
    ySalary(NULL) ,
    fName("") ,
    mName("") ,
    lName("") { 
}
```

I'd recommend always to use the member initializer list syntax, preferred to assignments in the constructor body. See here for example: [What is the advantage of using initializers for a constructor in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803079/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-initializers-for-a-constructor-in-c)

Comment: You should also note that a default-constructor isn't needed, he should have `Person() = default` if he wants the compiler generated one.

Comment: @0x499602D2 True, but that would be c++11 explicitely. Questionable though, if we should consider [tag:c++] referring to _the current_ standard.

Answer (score 0):

beside the previou answer, you can use in-class initialization (since c++11).

example:    const string &fname = "";

Comment: This would be a dangling reference